# How to prove that $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

If there is a function $f$ such that:-
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{n}}, n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}
$$
How can we prove the continuity of above function using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very useful identity: $(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b +...ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})=a^n - b^n$.

Plugging $a:=x^{1/n} , b:=x_0^{1/n}$  we get: 
$|x^{1/n}- x_0^{1/n}| = |a-b| = \big|\dfrac{a^n - b^n}{(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b +...ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})}\big| =\dfrac{|x-x_0|}{(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b +...ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})}$

Do you see where this is going?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon, c > 0$; then
$$
|x^{1/n} - c^{1/n}| < \varepsilon \qquad (*)
$$ 
iff
$c^{1/n}-\varepsilon < x^{1/n} < c^{1/n}+\varepsilon$, which holds iff
$(c^{1/n}-\varepsilon)^{n} - c < x-c < (c^{1/n}+\varepsilon)^{n} - c$;
if $\delta := \min \{ |(c^{1/n}-\varepsilon)^{n} - c|, (c^{1/n}+\varepsilon)^{n} - c \}$, then $|x-c| < \delta$ implies $(*)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\ge x\ge 0$ then
$$
(x^{\frac1n}+(y-x)^{\frac1n})^n\ge x+(y-x)=y \implies y^{\frac1n} - x^{\frac1n} \le (y-x)^{\frac1n}
$$
and by symmetry in consequence for arbitrary $x,y\ge 0$
$$
|y^{\frac1n} - x^{\frac1n}| \le |y-x|^{\frac1n}
$$
which proves Hölder continuity with exponent $\frac1n$.